# .NET MAUI Windows app. tabbed page white area

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-maui

Hello everyone I am developing a Windows app with .net Maui. I am using a tabbed a page and there is a little white area on the very right of the navigation bar. [narrow white area where it makes a contrast with green on the right upper corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4RFD.png) I do not know which causes it and couldn`t get rid of it. I am also adding the photos of my navigation page and appshell. I am assuming it has something to do with the appshell, because the background color I use on the weather page is actually not white, it is a yellowish color. Would to happy to have any suggestions.

AppShell code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp2.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp2"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
    FlyoutBackgroundColor="White"
    BackgroundColor="White">

    <ShellContent
        Title=""
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:WeatherPage}"
        Route="WeatherPage" 
        Content="white"
        />
    
</Shell>
```

Navigation page frontend code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp2"
    x:Class="MauiApp2.NaviPage"
    BackgroundColor="Black"
    BarBackgroundColor="Green"
    BarTextColor="White"
    SelectedTabColor="White"
    >
    <local:WeatherPage
        Title="Weather"/>
   
    <local:AboutPage1
        Title="About"/>
</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images.  Take the time to paste and properly format them as text.  And if you have a question about a specific UI quirk, take the time to annotate a screenshot to point to exactly what you mean.  Your description says both "very left" and "upper right corner" so it's difficult to tell exactly what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I corrected the question statement.